# Failed to evaluate expression Wordpress deployment

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I have a Wordpress instance deployed on GCP and haven’t looked at it in some time. When I launch into deployments I can see all the information I used to see but not the URLs for my Wordpress instance.   I have no idea where to start? Needless to say that I am not that technical…. I searched for the error message but the leads I found were way to technical.   I thought it may have to do that my credit card information expired for some time and that it may have been taken offline.  The Wordpress site  isn’t reachable analoger either.  Any leads are welcome.  Thanks

Comment: Billing needed to be refreshed - Problem solved!  Is there a way I can close this ticket ?`

Comment: You can post and answer and accept OR delete the question.